# c++ How to path LocalAppData folder

Tags: c++, windows

I need to find the path of this file:

`("C:\\Users\\*username*\\AppData\\Local")`

I tried everything but I couldn't because of the username

If anyone knows, can they explain how I should get the LocalAppData path?

Comment: @CherryDT for some reason i read c#, my bad

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way<sup>1</sup> to do this is to call [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) with [`FOLDERID_LocalAppData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid#FOLDERID_LocalAppData):

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <shlobj_core.h>
#include <KnownFolders.h>

int main() {
    PWSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT hres = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &path);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
        std::wcout << path << std::endl;
        CoTaskMemFree(path);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is also an environment variable `LOCALAPPDATA` that you could use, but it's not guaranteed to contain the expected value since it can be modified by the parent process.

---

<sub>**1:** Available since Windows Vista. There is an older function [`SHGetFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) in case compatibility with Windows 2000/XP is required.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) (for maximum compatibility).

You have to specify the `CSIDL` value for the folder you want, in your case that would be `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA`.

After Windows Vista, you can instead use [`SHGetKnowFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath), which requires a folder `KNOWFOLDERID`, in your case this would be `FOLDERID_LocalAppData`.

To use this, you have to include `<shlobj.h>`

Comment: This is not maximum compatibility but it is good enough for 2000/XP. Win95/NT4 only had the SpecialFolder version that gave you a PIDL (not that it matters here because LocalAppData had not been invented yet).