Programmatically set sub folder creation permissions C++
Based on what I've found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/permissions I've tried to programmatically set the folder permission to write, in order to be able to programmatically create a subfolder.
    void demo_perms(std::filesystem::perms p)
    {
        using std::filesystem::perms;
        auto show = [=](char op, perms perm)
        {
            std::cout << (perms::none == (perm & p) ? '-' : op);
        };
        show('r', perms::owner_read);
        show('w', perms::owner_write);
        show('x', perms::owner_exec);
        show('r', perms::group_read);
        show('w', perms::group_write);
        show('x', perms::group_exec);
        show('r', perms::others_read);
        show('w', perms::others_write);
        show('x', perms::others_exec);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    cwd = std::filesystem::current_path();
    std::filesystem::permissions(
        cwd,
        std::filesystem::perms::owner_all | std::filesystem::perms::group_all,
        std::filesystem::perm_options::add
    );
    demo_perms(std::filesystem::status(cwd).permissions());
        
    if(!std::filesystem::exists(graspdatafolderpath))
    {
        std::filesystem::create_directory("/GraspData");
    }

Ouput:
    rwxrwxr-x
    Unhandled standard exception of type "NSt10filesystem7__cxx1116filesystem_errorE" with message "filesystem error: cannot create directory: Permission denied [/GraspData]"; terminating the application

But, as, you can see, what I've tried, does not work
How to make it work?

You do know that a leading / will mark the directory as absolute and is the root directory. That means you attempt to create GraspData in the filesystem root directory, where normal users don't have access. Are you tying to create the GraspData directory in the current directory? Then drop the leading / from the path (and then there's likely no need to fiddle with the permissions).

Is cwd set to /? /GraspData is absolute path, ordinary users usually do not have permissions to create directories there.

As @Someprogrammerdude mentioned. Do you actually have permission to create a folder in the root directory? Try changing the path to a place in which you have permission to create a folder and see if it works there.

This sounds like an XY problem. Step back, forget about permissions and then tell us what you are actually trying to achieve.

Thank you very much for all your kind suggestions. Actually the issue was just caused, as rightly pointed by @Someprogrammerdude, by the leading /. Removed that in std::filesystem::create_directory("GraspData"), the subfolder has been then created. Thanks again for your kind prompt help

You might still have a serious problem with your code, since you're just using the "current path". In most cases, data files would be stored in a users "home directory" on a unix-ish system, and something like FOLDERID_LocalAppData on Windows -- not in whatever happens to be the current directory when the application is run.

Thank you @ChristianStieber for highlighting me this issue. I need, then, to create data subfolder in "home directory" for unix-ish, and in "FOLDERID_LocalAppData" for Windows. I've found this for windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70944799/c-how-to-path-localappdata-folder . What's the best way?

@Raphael10 comments are a bit limited to be pasting code examples; this is a bit on the quick&dirty side for now, but it creates a data directory for the project (following the usual naming conventions on the platforms) and makes it the current directory (so I can just do things without having to add the path), on both Windows and Linux: https://github.com/Christian-Stieber/Christians-Steam-Framework/blob/main/Sources/WorkingDir.cpp
